# One of the entries is not associated with the rest of the resultant entries

Tags: mysql

**I have this table and SQL:**

```
// Table

        create table messaging (
            fromid integer,
            toid integer,
            message text,
            message_time datetime
         );

         insert into messaging values (1, 2, 'asdf', '2015-04-01');
         insert into messaging values (1, 2, 'asdf', '2015-04-01');
         insert into messaging values (3, 1, 'fjfj', '2015-03-04');
         insert into messaging values (4, 1, 'lmno', '2015-03-31');
         insert into messaging values (4, 1, 'adfzx', '2015-04-03');

// SQL

        select id, max(message_time), message
          from
            (select fromid id, message_time, message
               from messaging
               where toid = 1
             union
             select toid id, message_time, message
               from messaging
               where fromid = 1
            ) q
            group by id
            order by max(message_time) desc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d248e/3

It returns the last entry where `fromId` or `toId` is `1` (the criteria being `MAX(message_time) DESC`), among multiple entries. They are correctly being sorted out by date, but if I get the message value for each entry, I do not get the message associated with THAT date, instead, I get the very first message from that `id`.

How can I modify the query so that the message associated with `max(message_time)` is fetched instead of the oldest one?

I'm stuck in this step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the aggregate function doesn't give you the corresponding row. You can especially see this, when you apply multiple aggregate functions, like

```
SELECT MIN(value), MAX(value) FROM your_table;
```

Therefore you have to use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to get the right row. [This manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) should help:

> ### The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column
>
> *Task: For each article, find the dealer or dealers with the most expensive price.*
>
> This problem can be solved with a subquery like this one:

```
SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article);

+---------+--------+-------+
| article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

> The preceding example uses a correlated subquery, which can be
>   inefficient (see Section 13.2.9.7, “Correlated Subqueries”). Other
>   possibilities for solving the problem are to use an uncorrelated
>   subquery in the FROM clause or a LEFT JOIN.
>
> Uncorrelated subquery:

```
SELECT s1.article, dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
JOIN (
  SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
  FROM shop
  GROUP BY article) AS s2
  ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price = s2.price;
```

> LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
```

> The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when s1.price is at its maximum
>   value, there is no s2.price with a greater value and the s2 rows
>   values will be NULL.